# Google Play Store - Precise Version Control

Tags: android, google-play

When uploading a new version of my app to the play store, I have to wait for it to be approved - usually around 4 hours - which is reasonable, except along with the update comes occasionally some database and script changes on my server which are not compatible with the current, live version of the app and are required for the update to function properly.

Is there any way to have my APK uploaded and reviewed without being immediately published when the review process is finished? This would allow me to then update my server code then immediately switch the update to live.

Comment: Well what about the other users that don't have your new version of the app? Like if you have v1 already live, and my phone and tablet have it, then upload v2, that doesn't mean that my phone and tablet will automatically get the updates. You should probably design your system to support multiple live versions

Comment: Well, considering that you cannot force users to take on your updates immediately (or ever), the timing of the release to the Play Store seems unimportant. Your server needs to support the update and all past versions. "...occasionally some database and script changes on my server which are not compatible with the current, live version of the app" isn't practical. So, update the server before publishing the APK update. Am I missing something?

Comment: When a required update is released, the (now) unsupported versions are locked out and redirected to an update screen. The problem is, I don't want to lock the phones out before the new update is actually available.

Comment: Also, the app will notify users when an update is available (mandatory or not) and this is done by me keeping track of available versions in my database since the app is available from multiple sources (not just Google Play). With Google Play's review time being unpredictable, this leads to my DB and the actual availability of the product being out of sync.